# How to Decompose $\mathbb{N}$ like this?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Partitioning an infinite set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12629/partitioning-an-infinite-set)
>   [Partition of N into infinite number of infinite disjoint sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51096/partition-of-n-into-infinite-number-of-infinite-disjoint-sets)

Is it possible to find a family of sets $X_{i}$, $i\in\mathbb{N}$, such that:

- $\forall i$, $X_i$ is infinite,
- $X_i\cap X_j=\emptyset$ for $i\neq j$,
- $\mathbb{N}=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}X_i$

Maybe it is an easy question, but I'm curious about the answer and I couldnt figure out any solution.

Thanks

Comment: In order to unify the various answers: The question is *equivalent* to write down a bijection $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$. There are lots of known examples, for example $(m,n) \mapsto m+\frac{(m+n)(m+n+1)}{2}$ or $(m,n) \mapsto (2m+1) 2^n$. Of course, $0 \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An explicit one.  $\mathbb N = \{1,2,3,4, \dots\}$.
For each $i$, let $A_i$ be the set of odd multiples of $2^{i-1}$.
\begin{align}
A_1 &= \{1,3,5,7,\dots\}
\\
A_2 &= \{2,6,10,14,\dots\}
\\
A_3&=\{4,12,20,28,\dots\}
\\
&\dots
\end{align}

Comment: We can think of $f(n,m) = 2^{n-1}(2m-1)$ as a very **explicit** bijection $f: \mathbb N\times\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ for Martin's answer.

Answer (score 18):

Take any bijection $f: \mathbb N\times\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$. (There are many such bijections, see Wikipedia article [Pairing function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function).)

Define $X_i=f[\mathbb N\times\{i\}]$.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance as I try to understand this definition. (1) Does `f[N × {i}]` mean the same as `f(N × {i})`? In other words, do the square brackets mean the same thing as parentheses?

Comment: @LarsH This is the notation which I use for [image of a subset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_%28mathematics%29#Image_of_a_subset); i.e. it means that $f[A]=\{f(a); a\in  A\}$. Some texts use $f(A)$ instead of $f[A]$. In this case you should be careful not to confuse it with image of an element.

Comment: Thank you. I was getting there, but you confirmed what I was gradually inferring. :-)  And that takes care of (2) as well.

Comment: Hahaha, damn it you're to good - I was just about to give the same answer. :D

Answer (score 10):

Let $p_n$ be the $n$-th prime number. That is $p_1=2; p_2=3; p_3=5; p_4=7$ and so on.

For $n>0$ let $X_n=\{(p_n)^k\mid k\in\mathbb N\setminus\{0\}\}$.

For $X_0$ take all the rest of the numbers available, namely $k\in X_0$ if and only if $k$ can be divided by two distinct prime numbers, or if $k=1$.

Comment: Sorry @AsafKaragila, but i cant understand you answer, can you explain me please. "My english is too bad".

Comment: @Tomás: $X_1$ is all the powers of $2$ (the first prime), $X_n$ is all the powers of the $n$th prime, $X_0$ is $\{1\} \cup $ all numbers with at least two distinct prime factors.

Comment: Ok thanks, i understood.

Comment: Another possibility with primes: Let $X_1$ be all the numbers divisible by $2$. Let $X_2$ be all the numbers divisible by $3$ but not $2$. Let $X_3$ be all the numbers divisible by $5$ but not $2$ or $3$, etc. Finally, throw $1$ into the set you like best (such as $X_{17}$) and you're done.

Comment: And if you insist that $0\in \mathbb{N}$, then toss it in too.

Comment: @asmeurer: Note that $0\in X_0$ since it can be divided by any number, in particular by more than one prime number.

Answer (score 5):

This is much like the answer by GEdgar, but takes into account the fact that $0\in\Bbb N$. Define $X_i$ to be the set of numbers whose representation ends with exactly $i$ digits $1$ (so in particular $X_0$ is the set of numbers that do not end with a digit $1$; it is obviously infinite (and $0\in X_0$; this is why I didn't take digits $0$), and you can get $X_i$ from $X_0$ by adding $i$ digits $1$ to the end of each element). I was originally thinking of binary representation, but it actually works for any base, in particular for base $10$.

Comment: "the fact th[at] 0∈N" -- according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_numbers#History_of_natural_numbers_and_the_status_of_zero, "There is no universal agreement about whether to include zero in the set of natural numbers".

Comment: @LarsH:  Yes, but if you don't think $0 \in \mathbb N$, let $X_i$ be the set of numbers that end in $i-1 \ 1$'s and it works the same.

Comment: @LarsH: I know about the controversy, as sad afair. But according to the law of the excluded middle, $0\in\Bbb N$ either is true or it is false; one cannot let it depend on ones mood, or convenience for a particular question, which one. (Though possibly it is independent of the axioms, like the continuum hypothesis :-). As anyone knows who does serious business with natural numbers, like combinatorialists or in a lesser degree set theorists, it is in fact true. Indeed, counting (as here final digits $1$) _can_ (and often does) result in $0$, si it had better be a counting number.

Comment: I agree that $0 ∈ \Bbb N$ is either true or false, i.e. either it is a fact or it is not a fact, within a given system of conventions; and that in order to do business with natural numbers, you need to be very clear about whether you are including 0 or not (and that it is very convenient to  do so). On the other hand, it is also a matter of convention, and experts differ on this defn. "Counting numbers" of course is a distinct term, which can be defined independently of "natural numbers" (with the same, or different definitions). Again I'm relying on the same wikipedia article.