# Expressing $\Bbb N$ as an infinite union of disjoint infinite subsets.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, prime-numbers

The title says it. I thought of the following: we want $$\Bbb N = \dot {\bigcup_{n \geq 1} }A_n$$
We pick multiples of primes. I'll add $1$ in the first subset. For each set, we take multiples of some prime, that hasn't appeared in any other set before. Then $$\begin{align} A_1 &= \{1, 2, 4, 6, 8, \cdots \} \\ A_2 &= \{3, 9, 15, 21, 27, \cdots \} \\ A_3 &= \{5, 25, 35, 55, \cdots \} \\ A_4 &= \{7, 49, 77, \cdots \} \\ &\vdots \end{align} $$

I'm heavily using the fact that there are infinite primes. I think these sets will do the job. Can someone check if this is really ok? Also, it would be nice to know how I could express my idea better, instead of that hand-waving. Alternate solutions are also welcome. Thank you!

**Edit:** the subsets must be also infinite.

Comment: Yeah I guess it's okay but not the way I would do it. I would just take a union over singletons personally but to each their own.

Comment: Um, why not $A_{i}=\{i\}$?

Comment: I'm sorry. The subsets must be also infinite. I'll edit the question.

Comment: How about: $A_{0}$ is all number that is not prime power including 1. $A_{i}$ is all power (not including 1) of the $i$-th prime.

Comment: That's nice. Simpler, also. Thanks! (;

Comment: It is incredible how often this questions comes up, how quickly it accumulates the same answers.

Comment: Another way of describing your construction is to say that $A_i$ is the set of numbers whose smallest prime divisor is the $i$th prime.  (And then stick 1 in somewhere; or, if that's too inelegant, let $A_i$ be the set of numbers $n$ such that the smallest prime divisor of $n+1$ is the $i$th prime.)

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51096/partition-of-n-into-infinite-number-of-infinite-disjoint-sets or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220057/how-to-decompose-mathbbn-like-this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is another way to do it.
Let $A_{i}$ consist of all the numbers of the form $2^im$ where $2\nmid m$. That is, $A_i$ consists of all the numbers that have exactly a factor of $2^i$ in them. So
$$\begin{align}
A_0 &= \{1,3,5,7,9,11, \dots\}\\
A_1 &= \{2, 6 =2^1\cdot 3, 10 = 2^1\cdot 5, 14 = 2^1\cdot 7, \dots\}\\
A_2 &= \{4 = 2^2, 12=2^2\cdot 3, 20=2^2\cdot 5, \dots\}\\
A_3 &= \{8=2^3, 24=2^3\cdot 3, 40=2^3\cdot 5, \dots \}\\
&\vdots
\end{align}
$$
In general $A_i = \{2^im: p\nmid m\}$. You can of course pick any other prime instead of $2$.

Answer (score 3):

I like @Thomas’s answer best, but I would have enumerated $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ and then taken the inverse images of the separate columns for the subsets.

Comment: I like this because it avoids everything but the essential set theoretic structure...

Comment: So how about enumerating $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ by $2^{k-1}(2m-1)\mapsto(k,m)$? Then your answer and Thomas's are the same.

Comment: Right, @HaraldHanche-Olsen, I guess the two are as alike as peas in a pod. Only thing is, that I had in mind a different enumeration of $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$.

Comment: I expect you did. And of course, your solution has the advantage of not requiring a specific enumeration, i.e., being more conceptual. (Which some people might consider a disadvantage.) But anyhow, my comment was slightly tongue-in-cheek.

Answer (score 3):

This is an alternate solution.

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be any pair of irrational numbers such that
$$1 < \alpha < 2 < \beta\quad\text{ and }\quad
\frac{1}{\alpha} + \frac{1}{\beta} = 1.$$ 
The two sequences 
$\displaystyle\;\left\lfloor\alpha k\right\rfloor\;$ and 
$\displaystyle\;\left\lfloor\beta k\right\rfloor\;$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$ 
are called [Beatty sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence) and it is known they form a partition of $\mathbb{Z}_{+}$.
Define two functions $\tilde{\alpha}, \tilde{\beta} : \mathbb{Z}_{+} \to \mathbb{Z}_{+}$ by
$$
\tilde{\alpha}(k) = \left\lfloor\alpha k\right\rfloor
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\tilde{\beta}(k) = \left\lfloor\beta k\right\rfloor
$$
We have 
$$\mathbb{Z}_{+} = \tilde{\alpha}(\mathbb{Z}_{+}) \uplus \tilde{\beta}(\mathbb{Z}_{+})$$ where $\uplus$ stands for disjoint union.
Replace the rightmost $\mathbb{Z}_{+}$ recursively by this relation, we get

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{Z}_{+} 
&= \tilde{\alpha}(\mathbb{Z}_{+}) 
\uplus \tilde{\beta}(\mathbb{Z}_{+})\\
&= \tilde{\alpha}(\mathbb{Z}_{+}) 
\uplus \tilde{\beta}(\tilde{\alpha}(\mathbb{Z}_{+})) 
\uplus \tilde{\beta}(\tilde{\beta}(\mathbb{Z}_{+})))\\
&= \tilde{\alpha}(\mathbb{Z}_{+}) 
\uplus \tilde{\beta}(\tilde{\alpha}(\mathbb{Z}_{+})) 
\uplus \tilde{\beta}(\tilde{\beta}(\tilde{\alpha}(\mathbb{Z}_{+})))
\uplus \tilde{\beta}(\tilde{\beta}(\tilde{\beta}(\mathbb{Z}_{+}))))\\
&\;\vdots
\end{align}
$$
As a consequence, if one define a sequence of subsets $A_1, A_2, \ldots \subset \mathbb{Z}_{+}$ recursively by
$$A_1 = \tilde{\alpha}(\mathbb{Z}_{+})
\quad\text{ and }\quad
A_n = \tilde{\beta}(A_{n-1}), \quad\text{ for } n > 1,
$$
these subsets will be pairwise disjoint. It is clear all these $A_n$ are infinite sets.
Since $\beta > 2$, we have

$$\tilde{\beta}(k) = \left\lfloor \beta k \right\rfloor > \beta k - 1 \ge (\beta - 1) k\quad\text{ for all } k \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$$
This implies
$$\tilde{\beta}^{\circ\,\ell}(k) = \underbrace{\tilde{\beta}(\tilde{\beta}( \cdots \tilde{\beta}(k)))}_{\ell \text{ times}} > (\beta-1)^\ell k \ge (\beta-1)^\ell \quad\text{ for all } k, \ell \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$$

As a result,

$$\bigcap_{\ell=1}^\infty \tilde{\beta}^{\circ\,\ell}(\mathbb{Z}_{+}) = \emptyset
\quad\implies\quad
\mathbb{Z_{+}} = \biguplus_{k = 1}^\infty A_k$$
i.e. $\mathbb{Z}_{+}$ is an infinite disjoint union of infinite sets $A_k$. Since there are uncountable choices for $\alpha$, *there are uncountable ways of such infinite disjoint unions*.

For a concrete example, let $\alpha = \phi, \beta = \phi^2$ where $\phi$ is the golden mean, we get something like

$$\begin{array}{rll}
\mathbb{Z}_{+} =
& \{\; 1,3,4,6,8,9,11,12,14,16,17,19,\ldots\;\}\\
\uplus & \{\; 2,7,10,15,20,23,28,31,36,41,\ldots\;\}\\
\uplus & \{\; 5,18,26,39,52,60,73,81,94,\ldots\;\}\\
\uplus &\{\; 13,47,68,\ldots\;\}\\
\vdots\; &
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the rule that you only take the multiples that didn't show up already, then you're fine, since by construction you'll be making all the subsets disjoint and by the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic every element will be in some $A_i$.

An example of simple infinite disjoint union would be $A_i=\{i\}$ and then $\mathbb{N}=\bigcup_{i=0}^\infty{A_i}$.

With edit: A simple way to split up $\mathbb{N}$ into a disjoint union of infinite subsets is to start with $A_0=\{0,2,4,\ldots\}$, and then let $A_1$ be every other element of $\mathbb{N}\setminus A_0$ (i.e. $\{1,5,9,13,\ldots\}$).  In general, let $A_n$ be the set containing "every other element" of the set $\mathbb{N}\setminus \bigcup_{i=0}^{n-1}{A_n}$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to put there that the subsets must be also infinite. I have edited the question. Thanks for pointing out the $20 $. But my point is, I can have an algorithm to construct the $A_n$ sets. But does it work?

Comment: I've added a construction I personally like, but yes, what you have right now works fine.  The only thing you need to show is that each $A_n$ is infinite, but this is not hard.

Comment: About the edit, I think I'm missing something here. By what you said, $A_0$ is the set of the even numbers, and $A_1$ would be the set of the odd numbers, and $A_0 \cup A_1$ already killed it.

Comment: No, he's saying take every *other* odd number. Take 1, leave 3 for later, take 5, leave 7 for later, take 9, …

Comment: Yes, the language is a little difficult to grasp, and I have not quite found a nice way to say it.  I do not mean "everything not in $A_0$", but in the sense that the even natural numbers are "every other element in $\mathbb{N}$".  Precisely what Harald is saying.

Comment: It would be easier to start with taking all the odd numbers. Next, take all odd multiples of 2. Then take all odd multiples of 4. In the $n$th step, take all odd multiples of $2^n$.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Yes, that certainly works.  It is very similar to Thomas' answer.

Comment: The name of that kind of similarity is “the same”. He beat me by 29 seconds; I guess that's close enough to be evidence of independent thinking.

Comment: I would assume it is as well. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still didn't get it. You are taking the "other" numbers by steps, and that's why you skipped $3, 7 $, etc?

Comment: Yes; $A_0=\{0,2,4,6,\ldots\}$, $A_1=\{1,5,9,13,17,\ldots\}$, $A_2=\{3,11,19,\ldots\}$, etc.

Comment: Ok. I got it. Thank you both for answering!