# Nice examples of finite things which are not obviously finite

Tags: big-list

This question is in the spirit of the question "[Nice examples of groups which are not obviously groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362446/nice-examples-of-groups-which-are-not-obviously-groups)".

There are many impressive finiteness results in mathematics. For example:

1. The finiteness of $\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbf R}/\mathbf R)$;
2. The finite-generatedness of homotopy groups of spheres;
3. The finiteness of the set of smooth structures on the $n$-sphere, for $n\neq 4$;
4. The conjectured finiteness of Shavarevich-Tate groups;
5. The finite-generatedness of Mordell-Weil groups;
6. The finiteness of class numbers;
7. The finiteness of the set of rational points on a curve $X/\mathbf Q$ when the genus $X>1$...

So, what are the nicest examples of finite sets which are not obviously finite?

Comment: Sorry for this very late comment, but I would like to know what $\overline{ \Bbb R}$ is. I don't think this denotes an algebraic closure of $\Bbb R$, because then it would be isomorphic to $\Bbb C$, and the finiteness of $\text{Gal}(\Bbb C / \Bbb R)$ is not hard to establish, in my opinion.

Comment: Moreover (and this is completely unrelated), I found in [that](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/134272) question a link to one of your [blog post](http://mathramble.wordpress.com/2012/04/19/a-divisibility-identity-for-eulers-totient-function/). I was wondering : are some articles of this blog still available anywhere ?

Answer (score 2):

The finiteness of the number of different $n$ for which Fermat's equation has a solution?

Comment: Hehe...of the finiteness of the set of all real functions which are differentiable at some point yet not-continuous  there, or the finiteness of all the basis of a vector space which are a linearly dependent set, or the finiteness of the set of all compact discrete infinite topological spaces, or...Anyway, +1