# Cardinality of the set of all bijections

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $A$ be an infinite set and let $S$ be the set of all bijections $A \rightarrow A$. Then if $\mid A \mid = \kappa$, then $\mid S \mid = 2^\kappa$.

I'm able to prove it for $A = \mathbb{N}$ by showing an injection $P(\mathbb{N}) 
\rightarrow S$, but how can I prove it for any set $A$?

Comment: You can have a look to [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27785/cardinality-of-the-permutations-of-an-infinite-set/) question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It suffices to exhibit an injection $P(A) \to S$.

Let $X$ be a subset of $A$, and fix a derangement $d_X:A \setminus X \to A \setminus X$ (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/134152/1508) for proof of existence of $d_X$). Now define the bijection $f_X:A \to A$ as follows:

$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
  x, & x \in X \\[2ex]
  d_X(x), &x \notin X
\end{cases}
$

The map $X \mapsto f_X$ is our required injection.

Comment: The existence of $d_X$ assumes that $A \setminus X$ has at least two elements. So if $|A \setminus X| = 0$ or $1$, then there are no derangements. Fortunately, one can avoid this issue by setting up an injection from $\mathcal{P}(A \setminus \{a,b\})$ to $S$ for some $a,b \in A$. See the answer in https://mathoverflow.net/a/86578/133798 for this modification. Please be aware that the roles of $X$ and $A$ are interchanged in that answer.

Comment: Why does it suffice to show an injection?

Comment: The argument here shows $|P(A)| \leq |S|$. To show an injection from $S$ to $P(A)$, observe that $|S| \leq |A^A|$, where $A^A$ is the set of all functions from $A$ to $A$. Now, $|A^A| \leq |P(A \times A)|$ because you can associate every function uniquely to its graph. Finally, $|A| = |A \times A|$ for an infinite set. Thus, $|S| \leq |A^A| \leq |P(A \times A)| = |P(A)|$.