# Find a bijection $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $f\left( x\right) \neq x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{N}$, $f^{2}=id$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Find a bijection $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $f\left( x\right) \neq x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{N}$, $f^{2}=id$.

My answer is:

Let  $f:=\begin{cases} 0,x=1\\ 1,x=0\\ x,x>1\end{cases}$

Thus, $f$ is not identity but $f^2$ is identity.

Can you check my answer?

Comment: $f(2) = 2$, so $f(x) \neq x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{N}$ is not satisfied. Instead, continue the pattern for 0,1 to 2,3, then 4,5,  and so on.

Comment: Try a function that is different in $n$ is even or odd (by example, add $1$ if is odd, and subtract $1$ if is even).

Comment: See Pierre-Yves Gaillard's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134152).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a great idea, but you've failed the requirement that $f(x)$ must always be something different than $x.$ However, you can adapt the approach you've already taken to fix it. How can you fix the fact that $f(2)=2$ and $f(3)=3$ simultaneously? How can you fix the fact that $f(4)=4$ and $f(5)=5$ simultaneously? Does this give you an idea for how to fix everything? Can you come up with a piecewise formula to accomplish this?

Comment: Let $f(2x+1)=2x$ and $f(2x)=2x+1$. Thus, $f(x)\neq x$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb{N}$. But, $f^2(2x+1)=2x+1$. I.e., $f^2$ is identity.

Comment: Is it enough?..

Comment: Well, if you've proved that all natural numbers have either the form $2x+1$ or $2x$ for some natural number $x$ (you should specify that $x$ is a natural number, by the way), then it should be fine. It wouldn't hurt to point out that $f^2(2x)=2x,$ too. Alternately, a piecewise formula of the type $$f(x)=\begin{cases}g(x)&x\in A\\h(x)&x\in B\end{cases}$$ makes the rest of the proof almost trivial. All you have to show is that $g(h(x))=x$ for all $x\in B,$ $h(g(x))=x$ for all $x\in A,$ $A\cap B=\emptyset,$ and $A\cup B=\Bbb N.$ In this case, you've probably already proved that last two facts.

Comment: Let $g(x)=x$ for all $x$ in {$0,2,4,...,2n$:$n\in\mathbb{N}$}$=A$ and $h(x)=x$ for all $x$ in {$1,3,5,7,...,2n+1:n\in\mathbb{N}$}$=B$.

Comment: So, how can I show $g(h(x))=x$ for all $x\in B$, $h(g(x))=x$ for all $x\in A$, $A\cap B=\emptyset$, $A\cup B=\mathbb{N}$? Are these clear?

Comment: You seem to have chosen $A$ and $B$ perfectly! Your notation doesn't make sense, though. Instead, you could say "for $x\in\{2n+1:n\in\Bbb N\},$"for example. Or, you could just say "for $x$ odd." A more dire issue is that you haven't chosen $g$ or $h$ correctly--neither $g(h(x))$ nor $h(g(x))$ is defined, and $f(x)$ is, in fact, the identity function!

Comment: As a hint for how to figure out $g,$ start with the formula $f(2n+1)=2n,$ set $x=2n+1,$ and substitute to get $f(x)=g(x)$ for $x=2n+1.$ We can do something similar for the $x=2n$ case.

Answer (score 4):

As Catalin pointed out in the comments, your $f$ is not correct.

Let $f(2k+1)=2k$ and $f(2k)=2k+1$.