# Number of bijections between infinite cardinal

Tags: set-theory

I'm trying to prove that if ${\kappa}$ is an infinite cardinal, then there are $2^{\kappa}$ bijective functions from ${\kappa}$ to ${\kappa}$. I would greatly appreciate any tips. Thank you.

Comment: A function from $\kappa$ to $\kappa$ is a subset of $\kappa \times \kappa$. So that gives you an upper bound. For a lower bound you could split $\kappa$ into $\kappa$-many two-element sets and consider functions that either fix or permute each pair.

Answer (score 6):

I would do it differently.

The number of bijections is clearly not more than $\kappa^\kappa=2^\kappa$.

Let $S$ be the set of subsets of $\kappa$ that leave more than $1$ element in the complement. Clearly $S$ has the same cardinality as $2^\kappa$.

To show that there are at least $2^\kappa$ bijections we give an injection from $S$ to  the set of bijections of $\kappa$. To do this we send each $s\in S$ to a bijection $\sigma$ of $\kappa$ such that $s$ is the set of fixed points of $\sigma$.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was going to give, but mine would have had about ten times as many words.

Comment: How can I guarantee that such bijection exists?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134152/prove-that-every-set-with-more-than-one-element-has-a-permutation-without-fixed the answer by bruno is my favorite

Comment: My edit was to change "'less than" to "not more than" in the second line....+1

Answer (score 2):

We know that there are at most $\kappa^\kappa\le(2^\kappa)^\kappa=2^{\kappa^2}=2^\kappa$ bijections from $\kappa$ to $\kappa;$ we have to show that there are at least $2^\kappa$ bijections. Since $|\{0,1\}\times\kappa|=2\kappa=\kappa,$ it will suffice to exhibit $2^\kappa$ bijections from $\{0,1\}\times\kappa$ to $\{0,1\}\times\kappa,$ which we do as follows.

For each set $S\subseteq\kappa$ define
$$f(\langle i,\ \alpha\rangle)=\begin{cases}
\langle1-i,\ \alpha\rangle\ \text{ if }\ \alpha\in S,\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \langle i,\ \alpha\rangle\ \text{ if }\ \alpha\notin S.\\
\end{cases}$$