# Can we find a well ordering on an infinite set with no largest element?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, well-orders

According to the well ordering theorem "[Any set can be well ordered](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjQ5cGDoevUAhVGyoMKHf3DDg0QFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FWell-ordering_theorem&usg=AFQjCNFhijPQ2Z0s2CEe6rQks2LznH5NNA)". Whenever we have a well ordering on a set, it is not difficult to construct a new well ordering with a largest element.
My question is:

> For a given infinite set, can we find a well ordering on it such that there is no largest element?

Comment: Set of natural numbers.

Comment: Induce the well-order by a bijection with a cardinal number.

Comment: Use Choice + transfinite induction to define it one at a time?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6501/is-there-a-known-well-ordering-of-the-reals

Comment: @CountIblis That question is not related to this one at all.

Comment: Move the largest thing to the front. If there's still a largest thing, repeat.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Note that that's what's going on in my answer, but all at once.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. In fact, there is a *canonical* way to transform a well-ordering into a well-ordering of the same set with no greatest element.

Suppose I have an infinite well-order $X$. Let $F_X$ be the set of elements of $X$ with *finitely many* things bigger than them - for instance, the greatest element of $X$ (if such an element exists) is in $F_X$, while (if $X$ is infinite) the least element of $X$ (which *always* exists, since $X$ is a well-ordering) is not in $F_X$.

It's not hard to show that $F_X$ is finite, since otherwise we could build an infinite descending chain in $X$ (exercise). Now let $I_X=X\setminus F_X$; this is a well-ordered set with no greatest element.

If $X$ is infinite, $I_X$ and $X$ have the same cardinality. If you want an explicit isomorphism, we can "move $F_X$ to the back" - define a new ordering $\prec$ on $X$, given by $a\prec b$ iff

- $a, b\in I_X$ and $a<b$ in the original sense of $X$; or
- $a, b\in F_X$ and $a<b$ in the original sense of $X$; or
- $a\in F_X, b\in I_X$.

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is infinite then $A$ can be put in bijection with $A \cup \mathbb{N}$. Now from the well ordering of $A$ you can ge a well ordering of $A \cup \mathbb{N}$ without a largest element ( in the obvious way ) and then back, a new well-ordering of $A$ without a largest element.

Comment: As an interesting aside, note that for the first sentence, we either need a weak form of the axiom of choice or the assumption (which is present here) that $A$ is well-orderable: it is consistent with ZF that there is an infinite set $A$ which is not in bijection with $A\cup\mathbb{N}$ (namely, any infinite Dedekind-finite set).

Comment: @Noah Schweber: Very interesting.! To do away with the bijection, I guess we could  just move $\mathbb{N}$ from the beginning to the end, similarly to the move in your solution.

Answer (score 2):

In the usual development of ZFC, a *cardinal* is defined to the the
least ordinal with a given cardinality. Infinite cardinals are "limit
ordinals" --- as ordered sets they have no largest element.